# Is the XML declaration required in custom media types?

Tags: xml, api, rest

Is the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

required in custom media types?

I am developing a RESTful API and I have custom media types such as:

```
application/vnd.mywebsite.com.order+xml
```

But I am not sure if the XML declaration is required in the response or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML documents SHOULD contain a declaration but it is not required.  Whether you are using a custom media type or not is not really relevant.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I figured but I wanted confirmation.